# Having installed Win&Ubuntu dualboot, can't boot Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, ssd, bootloader, dualboot

I've installed Win10 first

Ubuntu linux was second installed

Now, I can only boot into Windows, Ubuntu, despite it's there installed, I can not boot.

I have very old pc with primitive bios. Only thing related to boot is ability to select boot drive, which is now windows boot loader. No other options there.

Is there any way how to make linux working dualboot ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have lost the grub bootloader.
Follow these steps to recover grub:

Write an Ubuntu ISO (Preferably the same version which is installed) to a CD/Bootable USB.

Select to boot from the Live USB
Select the `Try Ubuntu` to run a live session.
Open terminal using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

1. Run `sudo fdisk -l` to see where Linux is installed.
2. Run  `sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt` where x is the number you have your
   Linux Distribution on.
3. Run `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda` to install grub.
4. Run `sudo update-grub` to update grub.
5. Reboot

If the `sudo update-grub` command doesn't run before rebooting, run the command once the reboot is complete.

Comment: I've followed your steps, just got stuck on last command, as Ubuntu replied that "command not found" even after reboot

Comment: @JZK Sorry, I've edited the answer. It is update-grub and not grub-update

Comment: Ah, thank you, but it still showing me the error "failed to get canonical path of. /cow